# Preferred allocation of nested structs

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc, c11

Is it preferable to dynamically allocate the 'inner' structs in a nested hierarchy? If the parent struct is dynamically allocated, does it even matter? Why/how does it matter? Just trying to build my understanding of implications of different, seemingly contradictory, ways memory is dealt with in a code base I'm dealing with.

For example, what are the benefits of:

```
struct Foo_type {
  int i;
}; typedef struct Foo_type Foo;

struct Bar_type {
  Foo f;
}; typedef struct Bar_type Bar;

int main() {
  Bar* b = malloc(sizeof(Bar));

  /* yada yada yada */

  free(b);
  return 0;
}
```

As opposed to:

```
struct Foo_type {
  int i;
}; typedef struct Foo_type Foo;

struct Bar_type {
  Foo* f;
}; typedef struct Bar_type Bar;

int main() {
  Bar* b = malloc(sizeof(Bar));
  b->f = malloc(sizeof(Foo));

  /* yada yada yada */

  free(b->f);
  free(b);
  return 0;
}
```

Are they equivalent/different?

Comment: (1) is simpler; (2) is more flexible. Prefer (1) unless you really need (2).

Comment: @Matt Ahh that makes sense. So much more clear after the fact :) Basically if you don't know the size of foo then go with 2... is that really, in principle, all you gain?

Comment: Yes, you got it right.

Comment: 2nd needs more memory.

Comment: There's not really any need for the second alternative unless you have specific requirements. For example, if the struct is huge you might want to heap allocate it just because of that. Otherwise, don't use pointers just for the sake of it.

Comment: As a side note, consider changing your typedef coding style to something more conventional: `typedef struct { } Foo;` is perhaps the most common style used. No need for struct tags.

Answer (score 1):

As an added to @AndersK. answer, the first method (non dynamic) is preferred when we want to emulate inheritance, declaring the base `struct` inside the derived `struct` and casting the derived as base:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo {
    int i;
};

struct bar {
    struct foo f;
};

static void func(struct foo *f, int i)
{
    f->i = i;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct bar *b = malloc(sizeof(*b));

    func((struct foo *)b, 1);
    printf("%d\n", b->f.i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case one, the struct is contained in one memory allocation block, so you can memcpy it and need only one free for freeing it.

In case two you occupy two memory blocks not necessarily beside each other so you will have additional hassle of keeping track of those two blocks.

If you start having more pointers and members in Bar_type you will increase the complexity of copying an instance of the type.

Comment: Brilliant idea but it only works as long as it is not a recursive struct.